# memcpy() throws exception after it gets called in a class to copy in another class variable.

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memcpy

I have two classes one is JPEG_Server and other is JPEG_Client. Inside JPEG_Server class I have let's say following declaration:

```
class JPEG_Server
{
   public:
    unsigned char recv_buf[6];
};
```

And in JPEG_Client class I am trying to copy the contents of *buf into recv_buf using memcpy function in its send function.

```
void JPEG_Client::send_data(char *buf, int len) //buf is coming from another class
{
    memcpy(&JPEG_Server->recv_buf[0], &buf, len)
}
```

But it throws an exception and enters into its .asm.

The exception is like this:

```
 Exception thrown at 0x00C85579 in JPEG_Client.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.

 If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

Can anyone help me or comment that what is wrong in using a function like this?

Comment: `location 0x00000000` looks like unintialized `unsigned char recv_buf[6]` member

Comment: You are writing on `NULL`, `recv_buf` is unitialized.

Comment: Try providing an [mcve].  The context in which your function will be called is definitely a factor in your problem.  Obvious possibilities are that `JPEG_Server` does not point to an object, or that `len` exceeds `6` or the number of characters in `buf`.   Also the `&` on `&buf` in the `memcpy()` is not strictly correct if your intent is to copy characters.

Comment: initializing it with 0 would work? or what should I do?

Comment: If writing to `NULL`, it will be `JPEG_Server` that is `NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `memcpy`, you need enough memory on heap (destination - recv_buf).

Your `recv_buf` point's to `NULL`, which means it is initialized to `NULL`. Assign him enough memory on heap:

```
void JPEG_Client::send_data(char *buf, int len) //buf is coming from another class
{
    JPEG_Server->recv_buf = new char[len]
    memcpy(&JPEG_Server->recv_buf[0], &buf, len)
}
```

Comment: Since it is a .cpp do I need to typecast malloc as well? Because it says like 
' Error (active)  no suitable constructor exists to convert from "void *" to "JPEG_Server" '

Comment: Fixed. Dont forget to use `delete[]` before exiting.

Comment: it didn't help me out. it says now like this: 
'Error (active) a value of type "char *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "unsigned char" '

Comment: Change `unsigned char recv_buf[6];` to `char * recv_buf;` and it will work.

Comment: Thanks that worked. But now after this another exception popped out after this statement which says that 'JPEG_Server was NULL pointer'.

Comment: You have to assign memory to `JPEG_Server`. Show us its declaretion.

Comment: As I am using it in JPEG_Client so I declared it as private 
     private: 
       JPEG_Server *JPEG_Server;

Comment: Yes but did you assign him some memory with `new` since it is pointer?

Comment: No. So, in the constructor of JPEG_Client I should assign memory some using new?

Comment: Yes, exactly, in constructor.

Comment: Just a question related to new[] operator. For example I am doing char *recv_buf= new char[1000000000000]; But it throws bad_alloc exception. How to handle this thing? Although initialization seems to be perfect to me.

Comment: Becouse that number is more bytes than you can alloc. It might be more than all your RAM lol. If you solved your problem, mark question as anwered :-)

Comment: Most systems are using _virtual_ memory, system can store some of memory to disc - temporary (its called swap). Iam not sure, you may ask new question for that or search on google :-) You are voting up, click on the accept icon which is under voting buttons :-) Have a nice day @kni